# How to know which checkboxInput is clicked in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've this Shiny code:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("a1", "test1", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("a2", "test2", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("a3", "test3", TRUE),
    
    verbatimTextOutput("vl")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$vl <- renderText({ input$a1 })

  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

That looks like:

[image]

I want to save a string variable that holds only the name of the current clicked boxes
I thought about something like this:

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("a1", "test1", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("a2", "test2", TRUE),
    checkboxInput("a3", "test3", TRUE),
    
    verbatimTextOutput("vl")
  )
  server <- function(input, output) {
    my_string = c()

    if(input$a1){ #if TRUE
    my_string = c(my string, "test1")
    }
    if(input$a2){
    my_string = c(my string, "test2")
    }
    if(input$a3){
    my_string = c(my string, "test3")
    }
    
    print(my_string) #print to consol

  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
myString <- reactive({
  checkboxes <- c(test1 = input$a1, test2 = input$a2, test3 = input$a3)
  names(which(checkboxes))
})
```

Comment: and where I write print(myString)? I wnat to print to console evertime I click on some box

Comment: @asdf1212 `observe({print(myString())})` (note the parentheses)

Comment: TY, it's wirking!